# Passing l3str string as a value to a key

Tags: expl3, latex3

I am using a string from l3str to pass as a value to a key. Passing the same text stored *without* using the string works. However, I get `Package Listings: language java undefined.` when passing the string itself.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myLanguage}{m}{
\group_begin:
  \str_new:N \l__aljumaily_language_str
  \str_set:Nx \l__aljumaily_language_str{java}
  %\l__aljumaily_language_str % prints java
  % \lstinline[language=java]$#1$ % works!
  \lstinline[language=\l__aljumaily_language_str] $#1$ % Doesn't work
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \myLanguage{public static void main(String [] args) \{ ... \}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a string variable, that has different catcodes. And declare new variables outside of commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__aljumaily_language_tl
 
\NewDocumentCommand{\myLanguage}{m}{
\group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nn \l__aljumaily_language_tl{java}
  \lstinline[language=\l__aljumaily_language_tl] $#1$ % Doesn't work
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \myLanguage{public static void main(String [] args) \{ ... \}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the tips. I kindly wonder when should I use strings instead?